# First-chance exception at 0x0070C75C in BunkerBuilder.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCC04

Tags: c++, exception, cinder

I'm getting this error when I try to store a variable in d.dwellerModel, in the my loadDweller() function.  I've marked the line with '//Error'.  This code hasn't thrown any errors like these before, and I haven't modified this code, which makes me assume I've made some modification to the headers/code of the class definition (Which I've also included below).  Thanks in advance for any advice/help given!

**The function in which the error is thrown:**

```
dweller loadDweller()
{
    dweller d;
    do
    {
        string temp = strIn;
        lineIn();
        temp = strIn;
        int lNum(currLine);
        if(checkOperator(strIn, "fName:"))          //first name
        {
            d.firstName = getRemainder(strIn, "fName:");
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "lName:"))         //Last name
        {
            d.lastName = getRemainder(strIn, "lName:");
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "pos["))           //Position
        {
            d.pos = loadCoord2();
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "jobType:"))       //Job type/job
        {
            d.jobType = getRemainder(strIn, "jobType");
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "jobPos:"))        //job position
        {
            d.machine = numInp(strIn, "jobPos:");
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "maxHealth:"))     //Maximum health
        {
            d.maxHealth = numInp(strIn, "maxHealth:");
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "currHealth:"))    //Current health
        {
            d.currHealth = numInp(strIn, "currHealth:");
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "strength:"))      //Strength
        {
            d.strength = numInp(strIn, "strength:");
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "stamina:"))       //Stamina
        {
            d.stamina = numInp(strIn, "stamina:");
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "agility:"))       //Agility
        {
            d.agility = numInp(strIn, "agility:");
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "intelligence:"))  //Intelligence
        {
            d.intelligence = numInp(strIn, "intelligence:");
        }
        else if(checkOperator(strIn, "modelRef:"))
        {
            model mod = masterList::getModelTemplate(numInp(strIn, "modelRef:"));      //Ensuring that the value can be returned [when debugging]
            d.dwellerModel = model();       //Error //Ensuring that the variable can be set [when debugging] by setting it equal to a constructor of itself
            d.dwellerModel = masterList::getModelTemplate(numInp(strIn, "modelRef:"));
        }
        else if(strIn == "model[")          //Model
        {
            d.dwellerModel = loadModel();
        }
        else if(checkOperator("Gender:"))   //Gender
        {
            d.setGender(getRemainder("Gender:"));
        }
        else if(strIn != "]")
        {
            _DEBUG_ERROR("Unknown operator!");
        }
        else if((strIn != "]") && file.eof())
        {
            _DEBUG_ERROR("Unexpected EOF");
            failed = true;
            //return d;
        }
    } while(!checkOperator("]") && !file.eof());
    strIn = "";
    return d;
}
```

**the section of the .cpp file that defines the class(es):**

```
class dweller
{
public:
dweller();
//private:          //Make the following variables private once all direct access has been changed over to function access
string firstName;
string lastName;

bool isMale;            //true = NPC is male, false = NPC is female
var::coord2 pos;        //The NPC's position

//bool hasJob;          //If the NPC has a job
string jobType;         //What the NPC's job is
int machine;            //The vector ID of the machine the NPC is assigned to (in the map vector list)

bool isSelected;        //Whether or not this NPC is selected by the player

int maxHealth;          //The maximum health of the NPC
int currHealth;         //The current health of the NPC

int strength;
int stamina;
int agility;
int intelligence;

vector<item> inventory;
float maxInvVolume;         //The maximum volume that the inventory can hold (the sum of the volumes in the inventory must be less than this)

model dwellerModel;

float armLURot;                 //The current angle that the NPC's upper left arm is at
float armLLRot;                 //The current angle that the NPC's lower left arm is at
float armRURot;                 //The current angle that the NPC's upper right arm is at
float armRLRot;                 //The current angle that the NPC's lower right arm is at
var::coord2 toolPosOnHand;      //The coordinates that the tool should be centered at on the 'dominantHand' model_segment

model_segment* dominantHand;    //A pointer to the hand that single-handed items will be assigned to
model_segment* nonDominantHand; //A pointer to the hand that the secondary position of two-handed items will be assigned to
model_segment* itemLoc;         //A pointer to the model of the item that has been assigned to the dominant hand
bool holdingItem;
item heldItem;

public:

void draw();        
void update();
bool setInvVolMax(float _maxVol);
float getInvVolMax();
bool addToInventory(item _item);
bool removeFromInventory(int inventoryID);  //Removes the item at 'inventoryID' in the 'inventory' vector
bool equipItem(item _item);
bool equipItem(int inventoryID);    //Equips the item at 'inventoryID' in the 'inventory' vector
bool unequipItem();
void setGender(bool isMale);
void setGender(string gender);  //Male or Female
void executeTask(string _task);
void executeTask(string _task, var::coord2 _pos);
void executeTask(string _task, var::coord2 _pos, block _target);
void executeTask(string _task, var::coord2 _pos, item _target);
void executeTask(string _task, var::coord2 _pos, dweller _target);
void executeTaskEffect(string _effect);
};

class model
{
public:
    model();

    model_segment root;
    vector<anim_container> animations;

    bool runAnimations = true;
    void draw(var::coord2 position, float rotation);
    void update();

    void newAnimation();
    void newAnimation(anim_container anim);

    void updateAnimation();
    void updateAnimation(vector<anim_container> *animations);
    void initializeAnimation();
    void initializeAnimation(vector<anim_container> *animations);

    void debugTree();               //Prints a tree diagram of the model
};

model::model()
{
    //app::console();
}

model getModelTemplate(int ID) //Returns the template model from the master list at "ID".  Defaults to an empty model class if the supplied ID is not defined.
    {
        if(ID < models.size())
        {
            return models[ID];
        }
        else
        {
            _DEBUG_ERROR("The requested template does not exist");
            return model();
        }
    }
```

**the section of the .h file that defines the class(es):**

```
class dweller
{
public:
    dweller();
    //private:          //Make the following variables private once all direct access has been changed over to function access

    string firstName;
    string lastName;

    bool isMale;            //true = NPC is male, false = NPC is female

    float movementSpeed;

    var::coord2 pos;        //The NPC's position

    //bool hasJob;          //If the NPC has a job
    string jobType;         //What the NPC's job is
    int machine;            //The vector ID of the machine the NPC is assigned to (in the map vector list)

    bool isSelected;        //Whether or not this NPC is selected by the player

    int maxHealth;          //The maximum health of the NPC
    int currHealth;         //The current health of the NPC

    int strength;
    int stamina;
    int agility;
    int intelligence;

    vector<item> inventory;
    float maxInvVolume;         //The maximum volume that the inventory can hold (the sum of the volumes in the inventory must be less than this)

    model dwellerModel;

    float armLURot;                 //The current angle that the NPC's upper left arm is at
    float armLLRot;                 //The current angle that the NPC's lower left arm is at
    float armRURot;                 //The current angle that the NPC's upper right arm is at
    float armRLRot;                 //The current angle that the NPC's lower right arm is at

    var::coord2 toolPosOnHand;      //The coordinates that the tool should be centered at on the 'dominantHand' model_segment

    model_segment* dominantHand;    //A pointer to the hand that single-handed items will be assigned to
    model_segment* nonDominantHand; //A pointer to the hand that the secondary position of two-handed items will be assigned to
    model_segment* itemLoc;         //A pointer to the model of the item that has been assigned to the dominant hand

    bool holdingItem;
    item heldItem;

public:

    void draw();
    void update();
    bool setInvVolMax(float _maxVol);
    float getInvVolMax();
    bool addToInventory(item _item);
    bool removeFromInventory(int inventoryID);  //Removes the item at 'inventoryID' in the 'inventory' vector
    bool equipItem(item _item);
    bool equipItem(int inventoryID);    //Equips the item at 'inventoryID' in the 'inventory' vector
    bool unequipItem();
    void setGender(bool isMale);
    void setGender(string gender);  //Male or Female
    void executeTask(string _task, var::coord2 _pos);
    void executeTask(string _task, var::coord2 _pos, block _target);
    void executeTask(string _task, var::coord2 _pos, item _target);
    //void executeTask(string _task, var::coord2 _pos, 
    void executeTaskEffect(string _effect);
};

class model
{
public:
    model();

    model_segment root;
    vector<anim_container> animations;

    bool runAnimations = true;
    void draw(var::coord2 position, float rotation);
    void update();

    void newAnimation();
    void newAnimation(anim_container anim);

    void updateAnimation();
    void updateAnimation(vector<anim_container> *animations);
    void initializeAnimation();
    void initializeAnimation(vector<anim_container> *animations);

    void debugTree();
};
```

Comment: This is a _perfect_ opportunity to [learn how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). I strongly recommend you learn how to properly use a debugger as soon as you possibly can.

Comment: `0xCCCCCC04` is close to `0xCCCCCCCC` which is a magic debugugging code that means uninitialised stack memory. http://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892

Comment: You are likely using a pointer that is inside an object on the stack where the pointer was not initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `class dweller` and `class model` in a header file **AND** in a cpp file?

And you have defined they **different** (at least `dweller`: I see a `float movementSpeed;` in the header file version but not in the cpp version) ?

I think that this is a little dangerous (if you allow me a little understatement).

Suggestion: clear the `dweller` and `model` definition in the cpp file and include in it the header file.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I thought I had checked that.  I've always defined the class within the .cpp file, and then mirrored it into the .h file, out of habit I guess.  Is there any reason to do/not to do this?   (Beyond just not having to type something twice?)

Comment: @Zachary D. - You're welcome. Yes, IMHO it's a bad habit. And not (only) because you have to type something twice but because you **must** be **sure** to type the **exactly** same thing twice. (continue)

Comment: @Zachary D. - Your problem it's a wonderful example (even IMHO): defining classes in two places, with a element more in only one place, you desynchronise your code. There is part of your code with a definition and another part of your code with an incompatible definition. So, by example, a part of your code (the one that know `movementSpeed`) try to read a member past `movementSpeed` (`agility`, by example), can read data that the other part of the code (that don't know `movementSpeed`) has written in another position (in `stamina`, by example).